# Identifying rows with same positive and negative values with particular order in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for an efficient way to flag the order as returned when there is both positive and negative entry present in data given negative entry is only present at the same day or later date from positive value.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = [['US', '100', 'Ven1', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17), -100], ['US', '100', 'Ven1', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 19), 100], ['US', '100', 'Ven1', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 25), -100], ['CA', 'AR-100', '1276238', datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 25), 10], ['UK', 'UKV', 'Daily', datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 12), 2500], ['UK', 'UKV', 'Daily', datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 12), -2500], ['UK', 'UKV', 'Daily', datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 14), 2500]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['region', 'productid', 'vendor', 'date', 'qty'])
```

Input:

[image: input]

Expected Output:

[image: expected]

Here -100 from 2020-05-17 is not flagged because corresponding positive value is not present in dataset before this date's negative entry.

My current solution is sorting, grouping the data and then checking value row by row inside loops. This works but I think this is not the best way to solve this problem.

```
match = []
df = df.sort_values(['date', 'qty'], ascending=[True, False])
df = df.groupby(['region', 'productid', 'vendor'])
for name, group in df:
 ...
 for i, outer_row in group.iterrows():
  for j, inner_row in group.iterrows():
    if (j > i) & (outer_row.qty + inner_row.qty = 0) & (i not in match) & (j not in match):
      match.append(i)
      match.append(j)
      ...
      df['returned'].at[i] = 'Y'
      df['returned'].at[j] = 'Y'
```

I have found some solutions but they do not consider any order when finding the rows with positive and negative values. Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the option of extracting a unique order identifier from the original data source? I don't see how you will be able to put together an exact solution with the information you are working with. (Assuming your tracking system treats a return as a part of a specific order)

Comment: There is transaction id field but that is unique for each transaction

Comment: In that case, if I were you, I would go to the powers that be and inform them that in order to get precise stats their returns process needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

You can create groups with the same absolute qty and then apply your logic:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = [['US', '100', 'Ven1', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17), -100],
        ['US', '100', 'Ven1', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 19), 100],
        ['US', '100', 'Ven1', datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 25), -100],
        ['CA', 'AR-100', '1276238', datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 25), 10],
        ['UK', 'UKV', 'Daily', datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 12), 2500],
        ['UK', 'UKV', 'Daily', datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 12), -2500],
        ['UK', 'UKV', 'Daily', datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 14), 2500]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['region', 'productid', 'vendor', 'date', 'qty'])

df['abs_qty'] = df['qty'].abs()
df['returned'] = False


def return_logic(d):
    if not len(d) > 1 or not (d['qty'] > 0).any():
        return d['returned']
    g = d.sort_values(['date', 'qty'], ascending=[True, False])
    g = g.loc[g[g['qty'] > 0].index[0]:]  # cut rows with no positive value before them
    ind = g[g['qty'] < 0].index.values
    g.loc[ind, 'returned'] = True
    g.loc[ind - 1, 'returned'] = True
    d.loc[g.index, 'returned'] = g['returned']
    return d['returned']


df['returned'] = df.groupby(['region', 'productid', 'vendor', 'abs_qty'], group_keys=False).apply(return_logic)
```

In the logic function:

1. Check to make sure there is more than 1 row and that there's at least 1 positive value.
2. Find the first row with a positive value
3. Flag every negative qty line and the line before.

This won't handle situations where there are consecutive negative qty rows